# Can't find selector causing transparency

Tags: css

I've been fiddling for a while here trying to see what CSS is causing my drop down menu to be transparent or show opacity.

Logically I think the selector I want is:

```
ul ul li: make not transparent
```

But I cannot see what's causing it in the first place so don't know how to remedy.

I would paste the html and css here but since I really don't know what is the relevant css I've created a fiddle with the nav here: http://jsfiddle.net/snjc2mh3/

If you hover over "flooring" or "paneling" the drop down menu is transparent. It should be a solid white with #f6f6f6

How do I set the drop down hover menus to not be transparent?

I'm aware I need to change the text color of the drop down menus to black but that's a separate thing for now.

Comment: Chrome console, go to `Inspect Element`, select the parent `li` you're trying to troubleshoot, and in the Elements pane right-click on it's markup and select `Force Element State > :hover`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is more than easy to find out using your browser’s developer tools, after setting the state of the list item to `:hover`. This is the rule responsible:

`.dropdown ul li.current_page_item, .dropdown ul li:hover, .dropdown ul li.on { opacity: 0.4 }`